# Inexplicable spaces between letters in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex

The following code

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Epigrafica}

\begin{document}
Abcde
\end{document}
```

produces the following result using XeLaTeX in a full updated TeXlive 2015 distribution:

[image]

Notice the s p a c e s between letters. I've tried other fonts, e.g. Arial, and they produce the correct result (without the spaces). It appears to be a strange thing with Epigrafica.

I should also note that I have used the Epigrafica font extensively in the past (last time was about a year ago) without problems.

What change (in TeXlive ?) may have lead to this behaviour and how do I fix it?

PS: The Epigrafica font is available via installing the `epigrafica` package.

Comment: The typical problem with `xelatex` is that the fonts aren't not installed. I can't compile this example since `Epigrafica` is not available for me

Comment: I have the full TL 2015 installed, the `epigrafica` package as well, but this is of no use to me. The fonts aren't found

Comment: Epigrafica is a Type1 font, and therefore not (yet) suitable for use through `fontspec`.  The good results you remember were probably obtained from `pdftex`.

Comment: `\usepackage{epigrafica} \usepackage{fontspec}` with `xelatex` won't work, and `xelatex` will fall back on Latin Modern instead. `\usepackage{epigrafica}` with `pdflatex` works just fine, and produces no spaces between the characters.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer hmm, strange. Have you `cp /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf` and then `fc-cache -fsv`?

Comment: @Thérèse the results were obtained via `xelatex`, just checked

Comment: @Sverre yes in `xetex`, the `\usepackage{epigrafica}` won't work. You have to use the minimal example provided.

Comment: Then perhaps at one time you had installed the `.ttf` version of the font, available from http://myria.math.aegean.gr/labs/dt/fonts-en.html in the archive `Epigrafica-for-Screen.zip`.

Comment: @niels: I've not copied that fonts .cfg by hand. I assumed this is done automatically by `TL`. Well, that's why I don't like `xelatex` ;-)

Comment: @Thérèse Ha! That's it! By using the `.ttf` font found there (`\setmainfont[Path={/home/user/fonts/}]{Epigrafica-Ortha.ttf}`) I get no spaces!

Comment: But I don’t understand the problem fully: without the TrueType version installed, `luatex` exits with an error complaining that the font can’t be found, while `xetex` produces an ugly PDF.  I don’t work much with `xetex`, so I don’t know why it doesn’t just exit with an error.  Looking at the properties of the PDF confirms that it’s using Epigrafica, not falling back on Latin Modern.

Comment: @Thérèse xetex could always also load type1 fonts by name. luatex could too at some time but the support has been dropped from the fontloader. I can confirm that the behaviour changed from TL14 to TL15 and it seems not to be due to changes of the fonts. Perhaps something changed in the harfbuzz library. But as it is anyway better to use proberly unicode encoded fonts ...